# LightBulb work - Beginner

Tags: java

i'm new to java so I have a beginners question.
I have a work to do on writing a light bulb program which in it I have to switch it off and on. RGBColor class (which you will see certain references to it in the code) is another class which the LightBulb class is based on. Here's the code which I've done so far on the LightBulb class:

```html
   
public class LightBulb
{
    private RGBColor _color;
    private boolean _switchedOn;
    private final int MIN_VAL = 0;
    private final int MAX_VAL = 255;
    
    public LightBulb(int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        _color = new RGBColor(red, green, blue);
        _switchedOn = false;
        
        if((red < MIN_VAL) || (red > MAX_VAL) || (green < MIN_VAL) || (green > MAX_VAL) || (blue < MIN_VAL) || (blue > MAX_VAL))
        { 
            red = MIN_VAL;
            green = MIN_VAL;
            blue = MIN_VAL;
        }
    }
    
    public LightBulb(RGBColor color)
    {
        _color = new RGBColor(color);
        _switchedOn = false;
    }
    
    public LightBulb(LightBulb other)
    {
        _color = new RGBColor(other._color);
        _switchedOn = false;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        String onOrOff;
        if(isSwitchedOn() == true)
            onOrOff = "On";
        else
            onOrOff = "Off";
        
        return ("(" + _color.getRed() + "," + _color.getGreen() + "," + _color.getBlue() + ")" + ", " + onOrOff);
    }
    
    public RGBColor getColor()
    {
        return new RGBColor(_color);
    }
    
    public void setColor(RGBColor color)
    {
        _color = new RGBColor(color);
    }
    
    public boolean isSwitchedOn()
    {
        if((_color.getRed() == 0) && (_color.getGreen() == 0) && (_color.getBlue() == 0))
            _switchedOn = false;
        else
            _switchedOn = true;
        
        return _switchedOn;
    }
    
    public void switchLight()
    {
        //_switchedOn = !_switchedOn; // option 1: Doesn't switch it to the reversed value
        
        if(isSwitchedOn() == true)
            _switchedOn = false;
        else
            _switchedOn = true; // option 2: Doesn't switch it to the reversed value either
        
    }
```

When i'm building a LightBulb object and trying to implement the switchLight() method, i'm not receiving the reversed value... I'll be happy to know if you have a tip for me on how can I receive it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears your logic is mixed for what a switched light is.  In the switchLight() method, you are setting the _switchedOn boolean correctly, however in the isSwitchedOn() method, you are not interrogating the _switchedOn boolean, you are checking the color and then changing the _switchedOn boolean based on the color.  I would say checking the color in this method is wrong because if you set the color to 0 to say it's switched off, which you are not doing anywhere, you are not keeping the original color anywhere.  I would change the following methods.

```java
    public boolean isSwitchedOn()
    {
        return _switchedOn;
    }

    public void switchLight()
    {
        _switchedOn = !_switchedOn; // This should work now.
    }
```

Also, I would check your (r,g,b) constructor.  What happens if red is not in the range, but green and blue are?  Is that what you intend?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried what you suggest but the thing is that when i'm doing it in this way, according to the toString method, the light bulb is "off" even when i'm putting (255,255,255) as values, which is not correct. I should receive "on"...

Comment: In your constructor, you set the initial state of _switchedOn to false.  If you're saying you want the light to initially be on if a non-zero color is passed to the constructor, you need to add that check in the constructor and then change _switchedOn to true.  Currently, all your constructors set the lightbulb to be off initially.  This does not change regardless of the code in the isSwitchedOn() or switchLight() methods.